# Primitive polynomial in ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading Yukie Algebra II and it says:

Let $A$ be a $\text{UFD}$ and $f(x)\in A[x]$. Then
$$f(x)\text{ is a primitive polynomial iff for all prime elements } p\in A, f(x) \bmod p\text{ is not zero}.$$

My textbook also says "It's obvious" but I don't know how to prove this at all. I need help, how can I prove this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What definition of primitive polynomial are you using?

Comment: GCD of all coefficients of $f(x)$ is an unit element.

Comment: Ha! So, what have you tried?

Comment: I read and checked the definitions again to find a key to the solution but I couldn't find out at all...also I'm so confused I found another definition of primitive polynomial, Wiki says $f(x)$ is primitive iff the GCD is 1.

Comment: The gcd being defined up to a unit, saying "a gcd is $1$" or "a gcd is a unit" is the same

Answer (score 2):

$f=a_nx^n+\dots+a_0$ is primitive $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathrm{gcd}(a_n, \dots, a_0)$ is a unit $\Leftrightarrow \nexists p \in A$ prime such that $p | a_0, p | a_1, \dots ,p|a_n$ $\Leftrightarrow \lnot (\exists p \in A$ prime such that  $f \equiv 0 \pmod{p}) \Leftrightarrow \forall p \in A$ prime $f \neq 0 \pmod{p} $

Here we used that a non-zero element of a factorial ring is a unit iff it is divisible by no prime element in the ring and that $\mathrm{gcd}(a_n, \dots, a_0)$ is divisible by $p$ iff $p$ divides $a_0, a_1, \dots ,a_n$.